# How do you change the value of a static final field using ASM

Tags: java

If the FieldNode can be gotten, can you use that to change the constant value that is assigned to the field? This field contains an instance of an object of that changes things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change private static final field using Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection)

Comment: No, that trick doesn’t work anymore also this is asm not reflection